# Can signal 11 be raised at a mov instruction from register to register?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have the following disassembled code from a core dump analysed with gdb.

```
   0x083dc366 <+194>:   call   0x83db38e <Buf::push_data(UBYTE const*, UWORD)>  
=> 0x083dc36b <+199>:   mov    eax,esi  
   0x083dc36d <+201>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c]
```

Is it possible to crash at the first mov instruction or the little arrow from gdb is not to be trusted?

Comment: You are likely not in the innermost frame and the segfault happened within push_data. Inspect $_siginfo or similar to get the real code position.

Comment: Thank you @PlasmaHH you are once again right on one of my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *only* way it could crash on that specific instruction would be if the memory was not executable (e.g. jumping into data bytes which happen to decode as a `mov`). Since it seems it's from a proper code section, that's unlikely in this case.

I suspect GDB is just showing you a place where the function call returns and the actual crash happened inside the called function. Maybe it does not have access to the function's code or decided to switch the stack frame for another reason. Inspect the full stack trace using `bt` and switch the frame if necessary using `frame #n`.

In extreme cases the dump itself could be corrupted and contain bad info. If you can reproduce the crash reliably, it's best to run the program under GDB from the start and catch the crash right when it happens, before it got a chance to corrupt anything.

Comment: This is it, I was not on the inner most frame, thank you very much for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

### NO.

A move between two registers should not be able to cause a segmentation fault since registers are not stored in memory but have special locations on the CPU.  The arrow in gdb is not showing the current line, it is showing the current value of the instruction pointer, or the next instruction to be ran, but the line before may not have executed yet so it can be the source of the crash.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to crash at the first mov instruction

No.

> or the little arrow from gdb is not to be trusted

The arrow should be trusted.

The most likely reason you have "nonsense" data: you have rebuilt the executable, or you gave the wrong executable to GDB, and so the executable that crashed had a *different* instruction at `0x083dc36b` from the executable that you pointed GDB at.